# flask upload CSV file without saving

Tags: python, flask

trying to place my text classification model into flask applications using  CSV file upload to read data without saving the uploaded .csv file and throw it into my classifier model print it on the result pages. below example code of my attempt :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

            file.stream.seek(0) 
            myfile = file.file 
            dataframe = pd.read_csv(myfile)
            return
        else:
            return "Not Allowed"

    return render_template("home.html")
```

This is my form

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
            <input type=file name="file[]" multiple>
            <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

exception occurred here

```
NameError: name 'allowed_file' is not defined
```

Any idea about this kind of issue ?

Comment: where's the allowed_file function?

Comment: def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this part of documentation : (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/)

But you have to add the function :

```
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS`
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a function called `allowed_file()` in your module? Or have you created it in another module and forgotten to import it? You’re feeding your filename into the function `allowed_file()` so that it can check whether the filename is permitted, but the `NameError` indicates that the function `allowed_file()` cannot be found.